# Insert results from Stored Procedure into table and add an extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert data from a stored procedure into a table for example,

```
INSERT INTO FailedLogins
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed'
```

This works fine, however, I'm running this against hundreds of databases using SSIS so I need to add @@SERVERNAME into my FailedLogins table for each record to match the corresponding server.

So the result set should look as follows:

```
LogDate  ServerName  ProcessInfo  Text
```

Comment: Can you edit the SP to incorporate the field?

Comment: Not on hundreds of servers.

Comment: is the table failedlogins on each server ?

Comment: No, it's writing back to one DB from every server.

Comment: so when can you refer to @@SERVERNAME ?

Comment: I'm with @t-clausen.dk on this... I'm not clear on how you plan to use @@servername here.  You could do your insert as is, then go back and update `FailedLogins` and set the `servername` value `where servername is null`... but that's really not ideal.  Assuming the SP is the same on every server, and you know every server name -- do it right, write and updated SP, and push it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @readerrorlog_results TABLE (
  LogDate date,
  ProcessInfo varchar(max),
  Text varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @readerrorlog_results
      (LogDate,ProcessInfo,Text)
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed'

INSERT INTO FailedLogins
      (LogDate,  ServerName,ProcessInfo,Text)
SELECT LogDate,@@SERVERNAME,ProcessInfo,Text FROM @readerrorlog_results
```